# parse string error missing command when passing to sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Can someone explain how to correctly pass a variable into `sed` and return only `881 747`? I tried:

```
coords=$(xdotool getmouselocation) #x:881 y:747 screen:0 window:56623110
echo $(coords)|sed '/[[:digit:]]/'
```

which failed for a few reasons (neither of which I can figure out how to fix):

1. I am not passing things into `sed` correctly
2. my regex is incorrect. I also tried: `/:[0-9]+\sy:[0-9]+/` which failed even worse. Do I have to run sed twice, once to get the x value and once to get the y value?

Comment: output from `coords` is in the comment after the first line of code. Is there something I should do to make it more obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are asking.

```
coords="x:881 y:747 screen:0 window:56623110"
echo ${coords//:/} | sed 's/[[:alpha:]]//g' | awk '{print $1,$2}'

881 747 #output
```

To break it down:

- `echo ${coords//:/}` is using bash string replacement to remove all instances of `:` from the output string.
- `sed 's/[[:alpha:]]//g'` removes all `[[:alpha:]]` characters from the output.
- `awk '{print $1,$2}'` prints the first two fields; in this case `881 747`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using awk only(no need to use sed).

```
coords="x:881 y:747 screen:0 window:56623110"
echo $coords | awk -F "[: ]" '{print $2,$4;}'
```

Output:

```
881 747
```